# JS Как отследить что пользователь перешел по кнопкам "Вперед", "Назад"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как определить что пользователь перешел на страницу с помощью кнопок "вперед" или "назад"?

На сайте вопросов и ответов, есть список вопросов. Нажав на вопрос скрипт запоминает идентификатор вопроса в хранилище и переходит на новую страницу, а потом когда пользователь нажмет кнопку назад, вернет назад и выполнит скроллинг до этого вопроса. Страница меняется `Ajax` запросом, поэтому встроенный скроллинг выполняется неправильно.

Пробовал вешать якорь с помощью `pushState`, но всё равно браузер при нажатии кнопки "Назад", игнорирует якорь. Прошу помощи, работа стоит.

Вот так запоминаю идентификатор вопроса.

```
//на странице списка вопросов, после клика запоминаю его идентификатор в хранилище, допустим 4657 

$(document).on('click', '.questions_list_box a', function() { 
    sessionStorage.setItem('questionID', '4657');

});
```

Теперь перейдя на новую страницу, мне нужно определить что будет нажата кнопка "назад", желательно уже после возвращения, а не в момент, потом после возвращения я выполню скроллинг и сотру переменную.

Также пробовал решить вопрос с помощью функции `window.onpopstate`, она срабатывает только в комбинации с

```
history.pushState({questionID: 4657}, null, null);
```

что логично. Я решил повесить его в корень новой страницы, вот так:

```
<script>
    history.pushState({questionID: 4657}, null, null);
</script>
```

Не работает, при нажатии "назад" ничего не выполнится

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {

    alert('zdes'); //не работает

};
```

Только если выполнить `pushState` в каком-нибудь событии например `onclick`, только тогда, а в корне страницы она не работает, по непонятным причинам.

Comment: на событии popstate - записывать нужную инфу в Sessionstorage, а при открытии страницы читать ее

Comment: Спасибо, это я тоже попробую, подскажите, а какие есть другие способы определить, что посетитель попал на страницу через кнопку "Назад"? Как это отловить? Через `onpopstate` приходится немного мудрить.

Comment: Не получается через `onpopstate`, чтобы эта функция выполнилась, необходимо вызвать `history.pushState`, а это только на новой странице, и даже если положить её в событие `onload` вот так `history.pushState({questionID: 1588}, null, null);`, он не работает, только через событие например `onclick`, т.е. пользователь перейдя на новую страницу обязательно должен, что-то выполнить, чтобы сработало.

Comment: При вызове `history.pushState` - событие `popstate` не срабатывает

Comment: В документации написано, что вызывает https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate и я пробовал. А как еще можно?

Comment: тогда я не знаю в чем у Вас ппроблема. Приведите воспроизводимый код - посмотрим

Comment: добавил код в вопрос.